# Samsung galaxy s7 submerged in water. How serious can I expect it to be?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s7, water-damage

I dropped my [Samsung galaxy s7](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s7-7821.php) in water. It was submerged for less than 10 seconds, I turned it off within 30-60 seconds after that. It was working properly when I pulled it out of the water and while I was wiping it's surface dry, and I also managed to shut it down cleanly. I've wiped the audio jack opening and the USB port with a thin piece of tissue paper and also dried out any openings with a hair dryer. On hindsight probably shouldn't have done that, but it's already done. I've pulled out the sim card, and at least the sim card slot looked completely dry inside. It's since been turned off and is completely covered by dry rice.

How much damage am I looking at? This is the first time I have had water problems with a phone with an unremovable battery, and it doesn't look like I can do much else with it at home. Should I take it to a repair shop anyway and have it opened and dried? I don't know how much it would cost, and since it is an old phone anyway I don't know if it'll be worth it if they ask too much. Since the phone seems to be pretty water resistant I am wondering if I can just brush this off.

How much damage can I expect? If the phone turns on, charges and works normally is it safe to continue using it as usual? I am okay with keeping it under rice for 24 hours or more if that's necessary. When is the earliest I can turn it on again?

Comment: The Galaxy S7 is IP68 certified - dust/water resistant up to 1.5m for 30 mins. The one question is how much pressure was created by the splash when it fell into the water as this could result is a pressure equivalent to a much higher water depth. And the other question is what water was it (tap water, salt water, chlorined, other chemicals)? Salt and chlorine can cause corrosion after a while.

Comment: for non IP68 devices i recommend to immediately disassemble and disconnect battery. you can heat device with open case in oven (not a microwave!) at very low temperature (50° degree celsius) but make sure there is no display foil and place it on a saucer with glass side (as less contact points as possible)

Comment: @alecxs what's non IP68? Given what Robert said above, I'm guessing it doesn't apply to my phone?

Comment: @Robert it was just a bowl of tap water in the kitchen, may be a bit soapy with dishwater liquid. The phone slipped and fell in, but submerged completely

Comment: i mean any other non waterprotected device. IP68 is just classification of kind of protection, don't take me literally

Comment: @alexcs how long do you think I should leave it in the rice? Do you have any ideas? Would it be any helpful given I've dried it a bit with the hair dryer?

Comment: i don't believe in rice, hair dryer is definitely worth a try. 24 hours in the sun is enough

Comment: is your phone back to life? :)

Comment: @alecxs nope. thinking of getting it dried first at a repair centre after the weekend. still not sure how much it would cost though

Comment: why do you think it is wet inside? (IP68 dust/water resistant up to 1.5m for 30 mins) i think repair center will harm more than repair according to this [video](https://youtu.be/k8eoiVUxA0A) i won't be the one who say just switch on but your device is most likely fine

Comment: @alexcs I took your advice and saved me a trip to the repair shop. Seems to be working fine.